# Resize small forms on large pages

Tags: html, css, forms

I have this user profile form which is pretty small.

The point is: the form/fields should be small but the page is huge. I don't need this fields occupying the whole page.

So what I wanted to do is to make the fields smaller.

The current structure is 2/12 to the menu and 10/12 to the form.

One way I could do it is to simply put the form inside of a smaller column , such as 4/12 or 5/12. But the problem is when the page is resized to a smartphone for instance the form should occupy the whole page again, like 10/12.

Where's the page:
[image]

Where's the code:

```html
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-2">

              <ul class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Profile</strong></a>
                <a href="my-account-password.html" class="list-group-item">Password</a>
              </ul>

            </div> <!--/col-md-2-->

            <div class="col-md-10">

              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name here" value="Wile E.">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputLastName">Last Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Enter your last name here" value="Coyote">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputTitle">Title:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Enter your title here" value="CEO">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email here" value="wilie@acmecorp.com">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group bottom-buffer">
                  <label for="selectEmail">Notifications:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="selectEmailNotifications">
                    <option>None</option>
                    <option>Daily</option>
                    <option>Weekly</option>
                    <option selected>Monthly</option>
                  </select>
                  <p class="help-block">Receive email notifications with all the most important metrics of your business.</p>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>Save Changes</button>
              </form>

            </div> <!--/col-md-10-->

          </div><!--/row -->

        </div><!--col-md-12-->

      </div><!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to resize it in small screens, You should use **col-xs** (*extra small devices and phones (<768px)*) and **col-sm** (*small devices and tablets (≥768px)*) classes. And If you don't want your form to cover whole the page horizontally, you can also use **col-..-offset-..** class for giving margin to your form.

```
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

          <ul class="list-group">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><strong>Profile</strong></a>
            <a href="my-account-password.html" class="list-group-item">Password</a>
          </ul>

        </div> <!--/col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2-->

        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2">

          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputName">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your name here" value="Wile E.">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputLastName">Last Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Enter your last name here" value="Coyote">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputTitle">Title:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Enter your title here" value="CEO">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail">Email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your email here" value="wilie@acmecorp.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group bottom-buffer">
              <label for="selectEmail">Notifications:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="selectEmailNotifications">
                <option>None</option>
                <option>Daily</option>
                <option>Weekly</option>
                <option selected>Monthly</option>
              </select>
              <p class="help-block">Receive email notifications with all the most important metrics of your business.</p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>Save Changes</button>
          </form>

        </div> <!--/col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2-->

      </div><!--/row -->

    </div><!--col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12-->

  </div><!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are using the bootstrap Framework you can define the behavior of The col- div using col-xs for mobile, col-sm for portrait tablet and col-md for landscape tablet. See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

If you feel limited by the default definition you Can also extend the grid system writing more specific media queries, e.g. for xxl screen